# MySQL syntax check

Tags: mysql

I have the following script which is giving me a syntax error and i have checked everything but can't find out what's wrong.
I appreciate any help on this issue please, please find the script below.
Regards Nader

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CalcDoseCount;
DELIMITER $$
create FUNCTION CalcDoseCount (DivType  Int, DivDose  varchar(300), DurationType  float, Duration  float, EveryType  float, Every float,OrderType int)
RETURNS Int   
BEGIN
        Declare SingleDose  int;
        Declare TotalDuration  int;
        Declare DivEvery  int;
        Declare DoseCount  float;

        set TotalDuration = Duration * case DurationType when 0 then 1 when 1 then 7 when 2 then 30 end;

        begin
        if DivType in (0,2,3) then
            if EveryType = 0  then -- every type is hours 
                set DoseCount = CEILING( TotalDuration * 24 / Every);
            else if EveryType = 1 then-- every type is days
                set DoseCount =  CEILING(TotalDuration / Every );
            else if EveryType = 2 then-- every type is weeks
                set DoseCount =  CEILING(TotalDuration / ( Every * 7));
            else if EveryType = 3 then-- every type is times
                set DoseCount =  TotalDuration * Every;
            else if EveryType = 4 then-- every type is times per week
                set DoseCount =  CEILING( TotalDuration / 7 ) * Every;
            end if;
        end if;
        If DivType = 1 then
            set DivEvery = right(DivDose,1);
            if  DivEvery = 0 then  
                set DivEvery = 1;
            end if;
            set DoseCount =  (CEILING(TotalDuration / DivEvery));
        end if;
        if isnull(DoseCount) then
            set DoseCount = 1;
        end if;
        if DoseCount = 0 then 
            set DoseCount = 1;
        end if;
        return DoseCount ;         
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

[image]

Comment: Please give us the syntax error details.

Comment: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CalcDoseCount; should probably be DROP function IF EXISTS CalcDoseCount;

Comment: You want to create stored procedure or function ?, because you drop procedure before.

Comment: I have posted a link in my post showing the error.

Comment: The function does not depend on any schema related objects, so if you could please try on MySQL workbench, it would be great.

Comment: ELSEIF not ELSE IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems , 1- you have a spare begin which you should remove and 2 else if should be elseif.

```
DROP function IF EXISTS CalcDoseCount;
DELIMITER $$
create FUNCTION CalcDoseCount (DivType  Int, DivDose  varchar(300), DurationType  float, Duration  float, EveryType  float, Every float,OrderType int)
RETURNS Int   
BEGIN
        Declare SingleDose  int;
        Declare TotalDuration  int;
        Declare DivEvery  int;
        Declare DoseCount  float;

        set TotalDuration = Duration * case DurationType when 0 then 1 when 1 then 7 when 2 then 30 end;

        #begin
        if DivType in (0,2,3) then
            if EveryType = 0  then -- every type is hours 
                set DoseCount = CEILING( TotalDuration * 24 / Every);
            elseif EveryType = 1 then-- every type is days
                set DoseCount =  CEILING(TotalDuration / Every );
            elseif EveryType = 2 then-- every type is weeks
                set DoseCount =  CEILING(TotalDuration / ( Every * 7));
            elseif EveryType = 3 then-- every type is times
                set DoseCount =  TotalDuration * Every;
            elseif EveryType = 4 then-- every type is times per week
                set DoseCount =  CEILING( TotalDuration / 7 ) * Every;
            end if;
        end if;
        If DivType = 1 then
            set DivEvery = right(DivDose,1);
            if  DivEvery = 0 then  
                set DivEvery = 1;
            end if;
            set DoseCount =  (CEILING(TotalDuration / DivEvery));
        end if;
        if isnull(DoseCount) then
            set DoseCount = 1;
        end if;
        if DoseCount = 0 then 
            set DoseCount = 1;
        end if;
        return DoseCount ;         
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the end of the script like this:

```
END 
DELIMITER $$;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, now the syntax error is gone but the function is not created, the result is as following.
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1305 FUNCTION CalcDoseCount does not exist